# How to setup a rest api for adminhtml only?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, rest-api

Magento 2 version 2.1.10.

Admin base url : `/admin`

Site base url : `/`

How can I create a rest api and make it available only under the admin base url, like `/admin/testapi` ?

Furthermore, some day I may want use a separate domain name like admin.store.com for the backend site, how can I avoid *CORS* issue, like calling `admin.store.com/testapi` from `store.com` ?

Thanks a lot for any ideas ~~

Answer (score 1):

To access any Rest API endpoint for admin only you need to defined its route like below in webapi.xml.

```
<route url="/V1/test/api" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\TestInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

In above code, this api endpoint can only be accessed for those admin users who have access of  **Magento_Cart::manage** resource. To access this api you need to pass admin token in header. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this does not address my question at all. My question is how to setup the rest api endpoint *under* admin site, and how to get around or deal with the CORS issue when I need to put admin site to a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this by allow step below:

`http://yoursite.loc/index.php/rest/V1/view`

**Api**

```
<?php
namespace Iota\Security\Api;

interface SecurityManagementInterface
{

    const STORE_STATUS_OPEN = 1;
    const STORE_STATUS_CLOSE = 2;

    /**
     * @api
     * @return array.
     */
    public function view();
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
namespace Iota\Security\Model;

/**
 * 
 */
class SecurityManagement implements \Iota\Security\Api\SecurityManagementInterface {

    public function view(){
        // Something
    }
}
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Ihor Vansach (ihor@magefan.com). All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details (http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php).
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Iota\Security\Model\SecurityManagementInterface" type="Iota\Security\Model\SecurityManagement"/>
</config>
```

**etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/view" method="GET">
        <service class="Iota\Security\Api\SecurityManagementInterface"
            method="view" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

For admin level access define by `<resource ref="Magento_Catalog::manage" />`.
And you `route` by `<route url="/V1/view" method="GET">`